# .NET Localization - Japanese characters shown as boxes

Tags: .net, localization, fonts

I am working on localizing a WinForms application through satellite assemblies. The problem is that elements such as Form Title, GroupBox Text and ComboBox Items is displayed as boxes. Other elements such as Label and Button Text display fine. All these elements are using the same Font setting.

One of the reason could be missing Japanese characters from the Font used but then other elements are showing fine with the same font. Does GroupBox, ComboBox etc use some other font internally?

I am testing my application on an English Windows 7 x64 by changing the Thread's Culture explicitly in code. Form Title Font could be tied to the System Font (that might change when I use a Win 7 with Japanese Language Pack) but what about the ComboBoxes and GroupBox Titles.

Comment: Doesn't the Windows theme dictate the default fonts?

Comment: @SteenT: Ya, when I switch to "Windows Classic" theme, I can see Japanese text in the GroupBox Titles but the Form Title and ComboBoxes still show the boxes.

Comment: Then it's the usual problem with Far Eastern (and Middle East) languages, where not all Windows fonts include the letters/characters/symbols.

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be that different Fonts are selected automatically by Windows for different controls. On a Form, some Japanese text is displayed fine in a Label but the same text is shown as boxes in Form Title or GroupBox Text.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old problem that appear in some Windows controls (such as textbox, combobox and listbox). We met this problem in older Windows version (2000, XP) but I thought it must dissapear in Win7.
Try to change your system locale (it's called "Language for non-Unicode programs" somewhere in "Regional Settings") and then run your program to see what happens. 
If it works well - then it's not your fault and you can relax because those texts will be shown OK for Japanese users.